# In boolean algebra, having trouble reducing (¬a∨b)∧(¬b∨a).

Tags: boolean-algebra

Starting with (¬a∨b)∧(¬b∨a), I'm having trouble reducing this to: (a∨b)⟹(a∧b)

I am lost with what is the next step after (¬a∨b)∧(¬b∨a). Is it this perhaps?:

¬(¬a∨b)∧¬(¬b∨a) ? And then work on from there?

Comment: What happens if you don't apply De Morgan's law to the first part of the sentence?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Then I can't figure out a way to reduce it further.

Answer (score 2):

First "FOIL" it (i.e. use the distributive property twice)  to get $$(\lnot a \land \lnot b)\lor(\lnot a\land a)\lor(b\land\lnot b)\lor(b\land a).$$ The middle terms are zero so go away and then just use Demorgan on the first to get
 $$ \lnot(a\lor b) \lor (b\land a)$$ which is the same thing as $$ (a\lor b)\Rightarrow(a\land b)$$

Comment: Could you help me to reduce this further? I'm unsure what to do next after distributing it twice

Comment: @Lendl edited it. That's the most I'll do. That's all the steps so you just need to understand them and write them out explicitly.

Comment: @Lendl Extended hint: in the opposite direction from spaceisdarkgreen's answer (+1), it would work out something like this: $$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\color{red}{(a \lor b)\implies(a \land b)} \;&=\; \lnot(a \lor b) \lor (a \land b) \\
 &=\; (\lnot a \land \lnot b) \lor (a \land b) \\
 &=\; \cancel{(\lnot a \lor a)} \land \color{red}{(\lnot a \lor b) \land (\lnot b \lor a)} \land \cancel{(\lnot b \lor b)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: thanks @spaceisdarkgreen. I'm just stuck on the last step. how you got from ¬(a∨b)∨(b∧a) to (a∨b)⇒(a∧b). which law takes you this this point?

Comment: @Lendl The usual definition of $\Rightarrow$ is $a \Rightarrow b = \lnot a \lor b.$ Is yours different?

Comment: That's the definition of the material implication connective.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern What but that do you suppose OP means by $\Rightarrow$ in the post? (The title is Boolean algebra... I only see one interpretation here.)

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Didn't see how close that was in time to my comment. Perhaps you meant to direct that at OP, not me. If so disregard.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen don't worry, I understand it now. Thanks for the help everyone.